# Can I perform git operations (add/diff/commit) on files in a repository when my current directory isn't in the repository

Tags: git

With svn, I was able to run commands on files in a checkout, without having `cd` into that checkout first. For example:

```
# Located in /tmp, running svn operation on /home/d5ve/checkout
d5ve@host:/tmp> svn add /home/d5ve/checkout/myfile.txt
d5ve@host:/tmp> svn diff /home/d5ve/checkout/myfile.txt
d5ve@host:/tmp> svn commit /home/d5ve/checkout/myfile.txt
```

When I attempt this workflow using git, I get an error:

```
# Located in /tmp, attempting git operation on /home/d5ve/checkout2
d5ve@host:/tmp> git add /home/d5ve/checkout2/myfile.txt
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I've tried using the `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` flags, but that also seemed to fail.

Any suggestions git people? I use this workflow a lot and really miss it when using git.

**UPDATE 2016** The current correct answer to this is to use the `-C` flag to git, which was introduced in version 1.8.5 in 2013. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35899275/357336

**UPDATE:** Based upon lunaryorn answer below, I've created a simple perl script which works out the location of the .git directory from the file paths, and sets the GIT_WORK_TREE and GIT_DIR environmental variables for the command.

Please have a look at: http://github.com/d5ve/rgit

USAGE: rgit COMMAND [ARGS]

Basically just replace *git* with *rgit* in a command, and you can run the commands from outside the repository.

```
cd /tmp    
rgit diff /home/d5ve/checkout1
rgit add /home/d5ve/checkout1/rgit.pl
rgit commit /home/d5ve/checkout1/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I execute a Git command without being on the repository folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149984/how-do-i-execute-a-git-command-without-being-on-the-repository-folder)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use both options together:

```
git --git-dir=/home/d5ve/checkout2/.git --work-tree=/home/d5ve/checkout2/ add /home/d5ve/checkout2/myfile.txt
```

Note, that `--git-dir` does not refer to the directory containing working copy, but to the `.git` subdirectory, which contains the repository itself.  git provides two environment variables to set these options permanently for a session:

```
export GIT_WORK_TREE="/home/d5ve/checkout2"
export GIT_DIR="${GIT_WORK_TREE}/.git"
git status
```

Comment: Cheers lunaryorn, that's combination I didn't try. I have a bunch of different repositories, so I'll try to put together a bash script which gleans the GIT_WORK_TREE and GIT_DIR from the directory mentioned in the command and sets them for the git command itself.
Something like `mygit add /home/d5ve/checkout2/myfile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Please check this slightly different question which has an answer working perfectly, different to the workaround proposed in the other answer here.

[How do I execute a Git command without being on the repository folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149984/how-do-i-execute-a-git-command-without-being-on-the-repository-folder/35899275#35899275)

According to some moderator I am not allowed to post the answer here (some kind of Chuck Norris fan I guess).

Comment: As linked here, the -C option to git is now the correct way to answer this question. This flag was added in git v1.8.5 in 2013. Cheers calandoa.