# git submodule update from different directory

Tags: git, git-submodules

I would like to run a submodule update from outside my git project. For most commands (e.g. `git status`), I can give git `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` arguments, like so:

`git --git-dir=/path/to/root/.git --work-tree=/path/to/root status`

However, running `git --git-dir=/path/to/root/.git --work-tree=/path/to/root submodule update` gives the result: `fatal: $program_name cannot be used without a working tree.`

I am aware that I can change into the `/path/to/root` directory, however I would like to know if git has the ability to update submodules from outside of the git project.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to run a git command from within the submodule outside the main repository by doing `git --git-dir=<path-to-repo>\.git\modules\<submodule-name>`

This is because a submodules git directory is located at `.git\modules\<submodule-name>` folder, not inside the submodule itself (UNLESS you created your submodule on top of an exsiting repository in the first place, in which case you can run `git submodule absorbgitdirs` to fix this). Note that from a fresh clone, the `.git\modules\<submodule-name>` folder will not exist until you run `git submodule update` for the first time.

However, I hit the same problem as you when trying to run `git submodule update` using a `--git-dir` of the main repository. It did not work both with and without specifying a work tree. I wonder if this is a bug, or we are doing something wrong.

However, because the first command I linked worked, you can just do the following:

`git --git-dir=<path-to-repo>\.git\modules\<submodule-name> pull`

Which will run git pull in your submodule from outside the main repository.

Answer (score 2):

My use case is init/updating a submodule within a Lerna/yarn workspaces repo.

The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35899275

Combined with looking at git docs for the [`-C` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--Cltpathgt) and git docs for [using submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), I arrived at:

```sh
git -C ./dir/to/submodule submodule update --init
```

The main thing to note from git docs, in contrast to using `--git-dir` or `--work-tree`, the `-C` flag "Run[s] as if git was started in `<path>` instead of the current working directory."

I then added as a script to my package.json to make updating easier and for contributors to get started.

**Update** The above command only works to init. I found I had to run this command to actually "update" the submodule to latest:

```sh
git -C ./dir/to/submodule pull <remote> <branch>
```

Note: the alternative to the above init command is add the `--recurse-submodules` flag when first cloning a repo:

```sh
git clone --recurse-submodules <git-url>
```