# Is it possible to create a Git hash object outside a Git directory?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-hash

I am trying to get the `git diff` between 2 strings. The following command works:

```
git diff $(echo "my first string" | git hash-object -w --stdin) $(echo "my second string" | git hash-object -w --stdin)  --word-diff
```

However, it fails if not executed inside a Git directory.

I believe this portion of the command is failing:

```
echo "my first string" | git hash-object -w --stdin
```

Is there any way around this so that it can be executed outside a Git directory?

Comment: This seems to address your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149984/how-do-i-execute-a-git-command-without-being-on-the-repository-folder?noredirect=1

Comment: thanks for the heads up ... if my code is executed on countless other machines, is there a way to reliablly set --git-dir ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I believe this portion of the command is failing:
>
> ```
> echo "my first string" | git hash-object -w --stdin
> ```
>
> Is there any way around this so that it can be executed outside a git
>   directory?

The problem you are having is because of the `-w` option that you pass to the `git hash-object` command. That option requires an existing repository as it has a side effect of [writing the object into the git database](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-hash-object#git-hash-object--w).

Proof:

```
$ echo "my first string" | git hash-object -w --stdin
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

$ echo "my first string" | git hash-object --stdin
3616fdee3ac48e5db02fbf9d5e1c2941cfa3e165
```

However, since your final goal is to obtain the `git diff` between two given strings you have to have a git repository if you want to do it with the help of `git hash-object`<sup>1</sup>. To this end you can generate a temporary empty repository:

```
$ tmpgitrepo="$(mktemp -d)"

$ git init "$tmpgitrepo"
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/tmp.MqBqDI1ytM/.git/

$ (export GIT_DIR="$tmpgitrepo"/.git; git diff $(echo "my first string" | git hash-object -w --stdin) $(echo "my second string" | git hash-object -w --stdin)  --word-diff)
diff --git a/3616fdee3ac48e5db02fbf9d5e1c2941cfa3e165 b/2ab8560d75d92363c8cb128fb70b615129c63371
index 3616fde..2ab8560 100644
--- a/3616fdee3ac48e5db02fbf9d5e1c2941cfa3e165
+++ b/2ab8560d75d92363c8cb128fb70b615129c63371
@@ -1 +1 @@
my [-first-]{+second+} string

$ rm -rf "$tmpgitrepo"
```

This approach can be packaged into a bash function:

```
git-diff-strings()
(
    local tmpgitrepo="$(mktemp -d)"
    trap "rm -rf $tmpgitrepo" EXIT
    git init "$tmpgitrepo" &> /dev/null
    export GIT_DIR="$tmpgitrepo"/.git
    local s1="$1"
    local s2="$2"
    shift 2
    git diff $(git hash-object -w --stdin <<< "$s1") $(git hash-object -w --stdin <<< "$s2") "$@"
)
```

**Usage**:

```
git-diff-strings <string1> <string2> [git-diff-options]
```

**Example**:

```
git-diff-strings "first string" "second string" --word-diff
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that you can `git diff` two strings by creating 2 temporary files containing those strings, in which case you don't need a git repository.

Comment: Excellent stuff, thanks Leon, adding all this functionality to my app now - much appreciated :D

Answer (score 1):

@danday74 I am unable to write a comment based on your feedback (due to permissions on StackOverflow) so here is my answer. You can set the environment variable [using](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git---git-dirltpathgt) `GIT_DIR`. If you do this on the multiple machines (you would need to be able to set this variable on such machines), then you will be able to reliably set `--git-dir`.

Hope this helps.